# Why is this method of iteration faster?

Tags: javascript, performance

My question is relatively simple. But I suspect the answer will be complex and interesting. I have two snippets of iterating through a loop in Javascript.

Snippet A:

```
//Fast
var l = arr.length;
for (var x = 0; x < l; x++) {
    dosmth = arr[x];
}
```

Snippet B:

```
//Very Fast
var l = arr.length;
var x = 0;
while (x>l) {
    dosmth = arr[x];
    x++;
}
```

Snippet B is significantly faster than snippet A. Why is that? I suspect it's because there are more scope or context changes in snippet A. But I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Seems like your logical checks are flipped x < l vs x > l

Comment: Which browsers did you test in? Is the second example faster in *every* browser? Also, how are you finding the run-time of the approaches?

Comment: Which JavaScript engine are you using?

Comment: 5 upvotes just because a typo which avoids all iterations?

Comment: He had code examples and it was well written/formatted. That deserves an upvote.

Comment: @Oriol: it's not necessarily a typo, unless the logical checks are flipped in the original code (which they probably are, but we don't know for sure yet).

Comment: Because in snippet B the loop does not run. I think there's a typo. You initialize x with 0, so x>l will never be true. If that's your real code,  will add this as an answer, but I suspect you meant x<l.

Comment: The fastest code is the code that doesn't run.

Comment: @Stephen A good question asking for a difference in speed should mention the tested engines, the inputs, and the results of the benchmark

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment, the latter is probably not hitting any iterations, since the checks are flipped. In the first you're checking x < l and the second x > l.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a slightly faster version with one variable and an implicit check but it runs backwards.

```
var i = array.length;
while (i--) {
    dosmth = arr[x];
}
```

Comment: I read that when you iterate an array backwards, some engines switch the underlying data structure to a hash, which would be worse. So I recommend against this kind of micro optimizations

Comment: Don't optimize without proper profiling and testing. First, I think you meant arr[x]. Second I would not trust this to be any faster (maybe even slower) on today's hardware.

Comment: but why should an engine make backwards iteration slower than upward iteration. it is somtimes necessary to iterate from the end.